# How to use memmap with U-Boot?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, driver, embedded-linux

I'll like to reserved the first 2 GB to the RAM because my hardware write in this position to the memory RAM and I need to the kernel don't touch this part to the memory.

I read to use this option need launch the order memmap in the bootloader and the bootloader to I use is U-Boot because I'm dessing to Driver-Kernel in Yocto OS.

I read this to example to use the memmap:

```
memmap=nn[KMG]$ss[KMG]
    [KNL,ACPI] Mark specific memory as reserved.
    Region of memory to be reserved is from ss to ss+nn.
    Example: Exclude memory from 0x18690000-0x1869ffff
             memmap=64K$0x18690000
             or
             memmap=0x10000$0x18690000
    Some bootloaders may need an escape character before '$',
    like Grub2, otherwise '$' and the following number
    will be eaten.
```

And I don't know to use in this case because I know this is easy to use in Grub2 but I don't know if it's possible using U-Boot, thankyou

Comment: What does this question have to do with `C` or the `linux-kernel`? Please do not spam tags! (this is not instagram ;) )

Comment: Do you know how to set kernel command-line arguments in U-Boot? This is just another one of those.

Comment: Finally I need to modify the .dtb for declare the "partition" RAM memory also I write in the U-Boot `memmap=0x7fffffff\$0x00000000` now I'm trying write this option in the U-Boot because I need to update Kernel and I like to don't wirte .dtb again. If I can, I'll write the finall solution to this problem for the future people to need reserve physical RAM memory.